# How to start with OpenGL ES?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, opengl-es

I want to learn OpenGL ES, but so far I don't know anything about it and I was wondering if there is a tutorial which stars from 0 knowledge. Remember that I don't know anything about graphics, drawing, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great start since it's specific to iPhone:

[OpenGL ES from the Ground Up: Table of Contents](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html)

Answer (score 4):

[iPhone 3D Programming Developing Graphical Applications with OpenGL ES](http://iphone-3d-programming.labs.oreilly.com/) by Philip Rideout

This book is available for free online reading.

Answer (score 4):

I heard that, one of the best tutorial to learn OpenGl for iPhone was written by a guy named Simon Maurice. But his website seems not available now. I have been searching for his tutorial all around the internet and at last I found a back up copy of the tutorial here.

**http://simon-maurice-iphone-opengl-tutorial.blogspot.in/**

Answer (score 1):

Theirs a slew of tutorials on their website
http://www.khronos.org/developers/resources/opengles/#ttutorials

Answer (score 1):

Ray Wenderlich has a nice set of tutorials (for almost everything related to iOS):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

The OpenGL ES tutorials:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5235/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-2

Also, I recommend once you have learned the OpenGL basics, to start using a graphic engine, since they act as wrappers for these kind of APIs like OpenGL. A good one is Cocos2d.

Check out the tutorials index I've posted above and you will find pretty good tutorials for Cocos and basic game programming.